# Show that the commutator subgroup of an abelian normal subgroup and whole group has special form.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian normal subgroup and $x \in G$. Let $G = AC_G(ax)$ for all $a \in A$, then
$$
 [A, G] = \{ [a,x] : a \in A \}.
$$
Any hints?

**EDIT**: What I have done so far. Let $y = [a, g] \in [A, G]$ be a generator of $[A,G]$, then I can choose some $a'$ and by the assumptions there is some decomposition $g = \hat{a} z$ with $z \in C_G(a'x)$, i.e. $1 = [z, a'x] = [a'x, z]$. Further
$$ 
 y = [a,g] = a^{-1} g^{-1} a g = a^{-1} z^{-1} \hat{a}^{-1} a \hat{a} z 
   = a^{-1} z^{-1} a z = [a,z]
$$
by knowing that $A$ is abelian. I have to show that $[a,z] = [a'', x]$ for some $a'' \in A$. I guess I have to choose $a'$ in some clever way, but I do not see anything. Some other things I know:

i) $[a,g] \in A$ for each $a \in A, g \in G$ by normality,

ii) the map $a \mapsto [a,x]$ from $A \to A$ is a homomorphism,

iii) $[A, \langle x \rangle] = \{ [a,x] : a \in A \}$.

Comment: Okay, I added what I have done so far.

Comment: You can choose $a'=a,$ as that factorization holds for all $a \in A,$ if I understand correctly the statement of the question.

Comment: Yes, this choice is possible. Then $y = [a,z]$ with $1 = [z, ax] = [ax, z]$, but where does this helps in establishing $[a,z] = [a'', x]$ for some $a'' \in A$?

Comment: This is Exercise 2, Section 1.5, from The Theory of Finite Groups by Kurtzweil & Stellmacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H=\{[a,x]:a\in A\}$.  First, let's show that the normal subgroup generated by $H$ contains $[A,G]$.  That is, we want to show that if we apply any homomorphism $\varphi$ that kills $H$, $\varphi(a)$ commutes with $\varphi(y)$ for any $a\in A$, $y\in G$.  To show this, write $y=bz$, where $b\in A$ and $z$ commutes with $ax$.  Since $a$ commutes with $b$, it suffices to show $\varphi(a)$ commutes with $\varphi(z)$.  Now write $z=cw$, where $c\in A$ and $w$ commutes with $x$.  Since $\varphi$ kills $H$, $\varphi(c)$ commutes with $\varphi(x)$, so this means $\varphi(z)$ commutes with $\varphi(x)$.  Since $z$ commutes with $ax$, this now implies $\varphi(z)$ commutes with $\varphi(a)$, as desired.

It now suffices to show that $H$ is a normal subgroup.  The fact that $H$ is a subgroup follows from your observation (ii).  For normality, fix $a\in A$ and $y\in G$ and write $y=bz$ where $b\in A$ and $z$ commutes with $x$.  Then $$y[a,x]y^{-1}=b[zaz^{-1},zxz^{-1}]b^{-1}=b[zaz^{-1},x]b^{-1}.$$
Since $A$ is normal $zaz^{-1}\in A$, and hence $[zaz^{-1},x]\in A$ as well, so it commutes with $b$.  Thus $y[a,x]y^{-1}=[zaz^{-1},x]\in H$.  Since $y\in G$ and $a\in A$ were arbitrary, $H$ is normal.

Comment: At first sight seemed to me quite an unconventional way of argumentation, but I really like it as by using homomorphic maps some of these "tedious" commutator-identities are just commuting laws in the image of the homomorphism, which are a lot easier to handle with. Thump up!

Comment: It's actually a very handy general technique in algebra: when you want to show that something is in the normal subgroup/ideal/etc generated by some other things, do computations in the quotient rather than explicitly trying to express it in terms of the generators.  It is of course equivalent in principle, but a lot of the time it's much easier to think about it that way.

Comment: Okay, for me its the first time I got "consciously" confronted with this technique; I am working my way through group theory by two books which are more or less "computational oriented", meaning they prefer elementwise arguments over such techniques. If you have them at hand I would be glad to hear from references where such arguments are used more, or if you can point me to similar proofs, preferable in the area of group theory!

Comment: I'm afraid there aren't any particular references that come to mind.  In my experience, this technique tends to be especially prevalent and useful in commutative algebra.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean by “$\varphi$ kills $H$”?

Comment: @Benny: That means $H$ is contained in the kernel of $\varphi$.

Comment: But how would it help to show $H$ is normal?

Comment: If $H$ is normal, then it is equal to the normal subgroup it generates, which by the first part means $[A,G]\subseteq H$.  (The reverse inclusion is trivial.)

Comment: Why we set $w$, which commutes with $x$? How could we know $z$ has the form of $cw$?

Comment: We know $G=AC_G(x)$, so in particular $z=cw$ for some $c\in A$ and $w\in C_G(x)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey But that is actually $G=AC_G(ax)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, I get it. $G=AC_G(ax),\,\forall a\in A$, then there will definitely be $G=AC_G(x)$ when $a=1$. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution. By putting  $a'=1$ in your calculation, you get $[a,g]=[a,g_1]$ with $g_1 \in C_G(x)$.

Since $G = AC_G(ax) = C_G(ax)A$, there exists $a' \in A$ with $g_1a' \in C_G(ax)$. So, using $[a,a']=[x,g_1]=1$, we get, using the commutator laws:
$$1 = [ax,g_1a'] = [a,g_1a']^x[x,g_1a'] = [a,g_1]^x[x,a'].$$
Conjugating by $x^{-1}$ then gives $1=[a,g_1][x,a'']$, with $a'' = (a')^{x^{-1}}$, so $[a,g] = [a,g_1] = [a'',x]$, and we are done.

Comment: Also a very good answer, but unluckily I can only give the bounty to one!