# Commutator of an abelian normal subgroup and the cyclic group generated by x

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working through the book "The Theory of Finite Groups" by Hans Kurzweil and Bernd Stellmacher.  Section 1.6, Exercise 1 is:

> Let $A$ be an abelian normal subgroup of $G$ and $x \in G$.  Show $[A, \langle x \rangle]$ = $\{[a, x] \mid a \in A\}$.

Defns:
Commutator: $ [x, y]=x^{-1} y^{-1} x y$

$[A, \langle x \rangle]= \langle \{[a, x^i] \mid a \in A, x^i \in \langle x \rangle\} \rangle$

As far as I've gotten:

Obviously {$[a, x] \mid a \in A$} is contained in $ [A, \langle x\rangle]. $
I need to show that $[a, x^i] = [a', x] $ for some $a' \in A.$  I've tried $a'= [a, x^{i-1}], $ and a number of other variations, but I can't find the trick that makes it work.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Isn't even more true?  If $a\in A$ and $x\in G$, then $x^{-n}ax^n\in A$ since $A$ is normal, so $[a,x^n]=a^{-1}(x^{-n}ax^n)\in A$.

Comment: So you're saying that I should show [A, <x>] is contained in A, which is contained in the set of commutators [a, x]?  Thank you for the suggestion!  I was trying to manipulate elements instead... probably the wrong approach.  But how do we show that A is contained in the set of commutators?

Comment: Related, though not quite the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182681/show-that-the-commutator-subgroup-of-an-abelian-normal-subgroup-and-whole-group

Comment: Your definition of $[A,\langle x\rangle]$ is not the usual definition.  Normally, the commutator of two subgroups is defined as the _subgroup generated by_ commutators from them.  (This turns out ot be equivalent in this case, but that is not obvious.)

Comment: I'm sorry!  You are of course quite correct.  I left my angle signs out.  I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

(The following is adapted from my answer to the closely related question [Show that the commutator subgroup of an abelian normal subgroup and whole group has special form.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182681/show-that-the-commutator-subgroup-of-an-abelian-normal-subgroup-and-whole-group).)

We may assume that the group $G$ is generated by $A$ and $x$ (if not, replace $G$ with the subgroup generated by $A$ and $x$).  Let $$H=\{[a,x]:a\in A\}.$$  First, let's show that the normal subgroup generated by $H$ contains $[A,\langle x\rangle]$.  That is, we want to show that if we apply any homomorphism $\varphi$ on $G$ that kills $H$, $\varphi(a)$ commutes with $\varphi(y)$ for any $a\in A$, $y\in\langle x\rangle$.  Since $\varphi$ kills $H$, $\varphi(a)$ commutes with $\varphi(x)$ for any $a\in A$.  Since any $y\in\langle x\rangle$ is a power of $x$, this implies $\varphi(a)$ commutes with any such $\varphi(y)$, as desired.

It now suffices to show that $H$ is a normal subgroup.  First, to show that $H$ is a subgroup, observe that $[a,x]=a(xa^{-1}x^{-1})=f(a)g(a)^{-1}$ where $f(a)=a$ and $g(a)=xax^{-1}$.  Both $f$ and $g$ are homomorphisms $A\to A$ ($g(a)\in A$ since $A$ is normal).  Since $A$ is abelian, a difference of two homomorphisms to $A$ is again a homomorphism.  So, $H$ is just the image of $A$ under the homomorphism $h:A\to A$ defined by $h(a)=[a,x]$, and so is a subgroup.

For normality, fix $a\in A$ and $y\in G$.  Since $G$ is generated by $A$ and $x$ and $A$ is normal in $G$, we can write $y=bx^i$ for some $i\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $$y[a,x]y^{-1}=b[x^iax^{-i},x^ixx^{-i}]b^{-1}=b[x^iax^{-i},x]b^{-1}.$$
Since $A$ is normal $x^iax^{-i}\in A$, and hence $[x^iax^{-i},x]\in A$ as well, so it commutes with $b$ since $A$ is abelian.  Thus $y[a,x]y^{-1}=[x^iax^{-i},x]\in H$.  Since $y\in G$ and $a\in A$ were arbitrary, $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the group G is finite. Let $k \in \mathbb{N_0}$ arbitrary.

$$
[a, x^{k+1}] = [a, x \cdot x^k] = [a, x^k] \cdot [a, x]^{x^k} = [a, x^k] \cdot [x^{-k}ax^k, x] 
$$
Note, I have used the invariance of commutators under group homomorphisms (using $a \to x^{-k}ax^k$) and one of the commutator formulas mentioned in the book ($[x, yz] = [x, z][x, y]^z$).
Finally we reduce the use $[a, x^k]$ term to a few $[-, x]$ terms by induction and use
$$
[a, x] \cdot [b, x] = [ab, x]
$$
for $a,b \in A$.
I have used that A is normal and abelian serval times.

Answer (score 1):

This can be shown by noting
\begin{equation*}
[a,x][b,x] = [a,x]^b[b,x]= [ab,x]
\end{equation*}
The middle equality follows because $[a,x]\in A$, which is Abelian. This together with
\begin{equation*}
[a,x^{i+j}] = [a,x^j][a,x^i]^{x^j} = [a,x^j][a^{x^j},x^i]
\end{equation*}
is enough (do you see why?)